# Why doesn't a CartoDB layer (using cartodb.js) on top of Google Map in Firefox on Ubuntu work?

Tags: javascript, carto, firefox

I'm creating a layer using CartoDB.js and putting it on a Google Map base layer.

This works on every other browser and platform I have access to (IE, Chrome, Firefox on OS X), but does not work on Firefox (31.0) using Ubuntu (14.04).

I made a simple [bl.ock](http://bl.ocks.org/ebrelsford/1505ba6ff37a5f421699) of this. The success callback is never called, but there aren't any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working here on Ubuntu 14.04.1 and Firefox 31:

[image]

Comment: ARGH you're right of course, thanks for proving that it was just some add-ons I had installed.

Comment: @ericbrelsford no problem!